# Unresolved reference: ContextAmbient while trying to go another activity from a composable function

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

Trying to go another activity from MainActivity from a jetpack composable function. like below

```
    @Composable
        fun SwitchingActivity() {

        val context = ContextAmbient.current

        Button(onClick = {
            context.startActivity(Intent(context, AnotherActivity::class.java))
        }) 
         {
            Text(text = "Another Activity")
         }
       }
```

But showing error

> Unresolved reference: ContextAmbient

What to do?

Comment: It was renamed to `LocalContext` in about 1.0.0-alpha02

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ambients were renamed as part of an early Compose update to 'composition local'. As part of that, `ContextAmbient` was renamed to [`LocalContext`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/platform/package-summary#LocalContext()):

```
val context = LocalContext.current
```